# Tomcat URL redirection to custiom page

Tags: html, tomcat, redirect

I'm using tomcat 9.0.70

Tomcat URL redirection to a custom page

I want users to see a custom message whenever they access the blueocean view. How do I get the pages starting with blueocean like http://www.example.com/blueocean/xyz/soon return a custom message not letting them through to use blueocean view that impacts the infra?